# Turning PHP String variable into PHP Script

Tags: php, string, function

I would like to learn how can I turn PHP String into a PHP script.

e.g.

```
$var = "echo 'Hello';";
```

and execute as

```
echo 'Hello';
```

If you need more detail or similar post exist please let me know.

Comment: `eval` is used, but it is __evil__.

Comment: Possible by using [eval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). But never do this!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by the PHP function eval. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

e.g:

```
$var = "echo 'Hello';";
eval($var);

// output:
// Hello
```

But take care it is an big security issue (it is not save and not good).

Answer (score 0):

Just use eval function see this link https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_eval.asp